# Short Connection

Tags: short-connections

I am looking to book a multi city flight to South America through a fare compare site.

Current itinerary:

- London to Lima (6th Feb)
- Lima to Rio (28th Feb)
- Rio to London (6th March)

My problem is that flight 1 goes London - Madrid - Lima with just a 1h 1m layover. However because it is "one flight" through one airline, would I be covered if I missed this flight through a delay on Iberia's behalf? i.e. would Iberia put me on the next flight either next day or whenever?

This is different to other questions as this involves "one flight" of many booked through a travel site. Thanks for you help!

[image]

edit: I am not taking any checked in luggage and it looks like Terminal 4 to Terminal 4 transfers recommend 45 mins minimum to transfer at the airport https://www.iberia.com/gb/fly-with-iberia/madrid-airport/connectiontime/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is tight but within the legal minimum connection time, provided both flights from Terminal 4 and the code-share qualifies for Iberia-Iberia connection. See https://www.iberia.com/us/fly-with-iberia/madrid-airport/connectiontime/

Since it is a single ticket, the airline will cover you and put you on the next available flight for free. In this case, this may only be the next day.

While you have a good chance of making it, there is a non-trivial risk, you'll miss it. Even if there is no financial impact, you need to decide whether you are ok with potentially loosing a day at your destination and dealing with a re-book, logistics, and haggling with unhappy gate agents around mid-night

Comment: If the incoming delay is not too bad, and if there are several passengers coming in on that flight, chances are very high that the outgoing flight gets held back to accomodate these passengers; it may be that agents wait at the gate to get you to the outgoing gate as quick as possible.